# What happens if I modify ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.getQueue()?

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.getQueue()` returns a `BlockingQueue<Runnable>`. This *appears* to be the actual queue used by the executor. Is it safe to iterate this from another thread? Is it safe to modify it?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safe to iterate this from another thread?

`Yes.` `BlockingQueue` is thread-safe. All queuing methods achieve their effects atomically using internal locks or other forms of concurrency control. For details go through this [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to iterate the `BlockingQueue` remembering the caveat from the Javadoc

> "Iteration over this queue is not guaranteed to traverse tasks in the
>   order in which they will execute."

It is safe to modify the `BlockingQueue` from one thread and see it in another thread, as long as you remember that any modification to the fields on the actual Runnable objects, will only show up in the other thread if they've been declared `volatile`.

Comment: What happens to the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor if I modify this queue? Won't it affect the tasks it's executing? Aren't tasks normally supposed to be submitted through the Executor's interface functions?